# php explode only pre delimiter and ignore rest

Tags: php, explode

Is it possible to explode only the text pre delimiter (before the --), but ignore everything after the delimiter on each new line of the entire string.

For instance:

```
string one -- string two
string three -- string four
string five -- string six
```

I only want to explode **string one, string three** and **string five** and ignore string two, string four and string six.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, so helpful... care to elaborate?

Comment: You merely need to `explode()` them, and just not use the second component. You may [use `list()` for that.](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) as in `list($firstpart,) = explode(" -- ", $fullstring);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's better than any of the answers so far imo. not point in writing something fancy when simple tools will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a multistep process.

- First explode by new line
- Second, loop though the lines and explode by ' -- '
- Third, output the first of the matches.

**PHP Example**

```
$Param = <<<LONG
string one -- string two
string three -- string four
string five -- string six
LONG;

$Lines = explode("\n", $Param);

$Output = [];
foreach($Lines as $line) {
    $line = explode(" -- ", $line);
    $Output[] = $line[0];
}

var_dump($Output);
```

**Example Output**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'string one' (length=10)
  1 => string 'string three' (length=12)
  2 => string 'string five' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
echo implode(",", array_map(function ($v) {
    return current(explode("--", $v));
}, explode("\n", $string)));
```

[View Output](http://eval.in/31441)

```
string one ,string three ,string five
```

Comment: Sexy, Baba. Very sexy (much more preferable to the foreach).

Comment: `$array = array_map(function ($v) {
 return current(explode("--", $v));
}, explode("\n", $string));` is all you need